Every commutative ring with 1 that has zero divisors and non trivial nilpotent elements has exactly one minimal prime ideal.
Given a commutativ Ring $A$ with $1$ and zerodivisors. In section 1.11 of Reids Undergraduate Commutative Algebra there is a Proposition:

Let A be a ring with zerodivisors. Then A has either nonzero nilpotent elements or more than one minimal prime ideal.

In the section 1.10 we had the Corollay
$$\mathrm{nildrad}(A) = \bigcap_{P \in \mathrm{Spec}(A)} P.$$
We get that also
$$
\mathrm{nildrad}(A) = \bigcap_{P \in \mathrm{Spec}(A)} P =
\bigcap_{P \in \mathrm{Spec}(A), \ P \ \mathrm{minimal}} P.
$$
Using this the book shows that if $\mathrm{nilrad}(A) = 0$, we have that $A$ has more than one minimal prime ideal, because
$$
0 = 
\bigcap_{P \in \mathrm{Spec}(A), \ P \ \mathrm{minimal}} P.
$$
Hence, if $A$ only had one minimal prime ideal $P$, then $P = 0$ but that would imply that $A$ is an integral domain.
The book does not proof that $\mathrm{nilrad} \not= 0$ implies that A does contain exactly one minimal prime ideal. So I wonder if that is the case.
Note that this is equivalent to showing that $\mathrm{nilrad}(A)$ is prime, because

If there is only one minimal prime ideal $P$, then $\mathrm{nilrad}(A) = P$ is prime.
If $\mathrm{nilrad}(A)$ is prime, then because of $\mathrm{nilrad}(A) \subseteq P$ for all minimal prime ideals P, it follows that $\mathrm{nilrad}(A) = P$ for all minimal prime ideals P. So there is exactly one minimal prime ideal $P = \mathrm{nilrad}(A)$.

Suppose that $\mathrm{nilrad}(A) \not= 0$ would imply $\mathrm{nilrad}(A) = P$ is a prime ideal. Hence for $ab \in \mathrm{nilrad}(A)$ we have $a \in \mathrm{nilrad}(A)$ or $b \in \mathrm{nilrad}(A)$. I feel like there are some counter examples with $ab$ nilpotent but $a$ and $b$ not nilpotent.
Is it possible to proof the statement or are there any counter examples?

Try $k[x,y] / (x^2, y^2-1)$

In $A = k[x,y]/(x^2,y^2-1)$ this should work: $a = y+1$ and $b=x+y-1$. Thanks!

Also $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$.
